# Show that $ \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{1 + a_ix} = nx $, where $ n > 1 $ and $ a_i > 0 $, has only a positive real solution.

Tags: calculus

I'm only able to use at most the Intermediate Value Theorem. I've already shown that there is a positive solution, but I'm struggling to prove the uniqueness. I tried by the way of the contradiction, supposing that there are two different positive solutions, but I didn't reach to the contradiction. I also tried supposing that, if $ x_0 $ is a solution, $ \displaystyle \forall \delta >0, \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{1 + a_1(x_0 + \delta)} < n(x_0+\delta) $, but I can't verify the inequality. I'd like to see the solution by these ways.

Comment: subtract one side from the other and try taking a derivative to see if your function is monotone.

Comment: But at the moment I can't use derivatives

Comment: Then prove that the function is monotone without using derivatives

Comment: Thank you! I showed that the function is monotone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{a_i}{x}} = n$$

Study the functions $f_i(y)=y^2+a_iy$ for all $i=1,...,n$. The functions are increasing in $\mathbb{R}_+$ as for all $y_1 <y_2$, we have
$$f_i(y_1)-f_i(y_2) = (y_1-y_2)(y_1+y_2+a_i) <0$$

Hence, the functions $x \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{a_i}{x}} = \sqrt{f_i\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)}$ are decreasing in $\mathbb{R}_+$  for all  $i=1,...,n$. We deduce that the function
$$g(x):= \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{a_i}{x}}$$
is also decreasing in $\mathbb{R}_+$ .

So, the equation $g(x) = n$ has at most one postive real solution.

From what you proved before, we can conclude that your equation has a unique positive real solution.